# VB - button click event not working properly

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, events, button, click

In my windows app i have a button which is only visible when a user selects a certain value on a DropDownList.

For some reason the button does not work when i click on it.

I've enabled the button on page load and it works, however when i choose the value on the Dropdownlist the button does not work.

Is there something im missing here? any feedback would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Code:

```
Protected Sub DropDownList4_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles DropDownList4.SelectedIndexChanged
    If DropDownList4.SelectedValue = "Yes" Then
        btnInsert.Visible = True
    Endif
End Sub

Protected Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnInsert.Click
    Response.Redirect("Menu.aspx")
    DropDownList4.SelectedValue = "Yes"
    txtfirstName.Text = ""
    txtSurname.Text = ""
    txtJobTitle.Text = ""
    txtCountry.Text = ""
    txtWork.Text = ""
    DropDownList7.SelectedValue = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you provide the code that is supposed to make the button visible/enabled?

Comment: It is a web application... here is a edited version of the code.

Comment: Protected Sub DropDownList4_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles DropDownList4.SelectedIndexChanged
If DropDownList4.SelectedValue = "Yes" Then
btnInsert.Visible = True
Endif  
End Sub

Protected Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnInsert.Click
Response.Redirect("Menu.aspx")
DropDownList4.SelectedValue = "Yes"
txtfirstName.Text = ""
   txtSurname.Text = ""
        txtJobTitle.Text = ""
        txtCountry.Text = ""
        txtWork.Text = ""
        DropDownList7.SelectedValue = ""


    End Sub

Comment: apologies for the formatting!

Comment: @user765942: I added your code to the question with an edit... in the future, it's better practice to do that rather than to post it in the comments.

Comment: So from the way you've phrased your question it sounds like the button appears as desired but doesn't work when clicked... however, it looks like your `End If` isn't formatted properly, which would theoretically make the button not appear at all? I'm assuming that's not your problem...

Comment: Have you discovered the solution to your problem? If you have please post your solution or accept an answer as the accepted answer if one of them match your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what we can see from your provided code all you are doing is changing visibility. Are you disabling the button anywhere else? Also Check the properties of the button in the design view to ensure that you did not accidentally changed the Enabled property to "False". It has been a while since I have done any web applications but if you are programically changing the enabled value of the button, I would suggest adding an Enabled = True line to your selected index change subroutine:

> If DropDownList4.SelectedValue = "Yes"
>       Then
>          btnInsert.Visible = True
>            btnInsert.Enabled = True
>       Endif

It has been a while for me so I can't remember if it is .Enabled or something else.

There is also the possibility that you have a Panel or some such over your button and that is preventing you from actually clicking on the button.

Also, put a break point on the first line of your button click event and make sure that you are not getting there as opposed to entering the code and it not running the way you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Try `SelectedItem.Value` instead, like this

```
Protected Sub DropDownList4_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles DropDownList4.SelectedIndexChanged
    If DropDownList4.SelectedItem.Value = "Yes" Then
        btnInsert.Visible = True
    Endif
End Sub
```